# "fatal: strange pathname '-im/somerepo.git' blocked

Tags: git, bitbucket

Everything worked great until today.

I've didn't change anything on my machine.

On Ubuntu 16.04 I want to make "git fetch" from the remote repo on BitBucket, but got this error:

```
fatal: strange pathname '-im/somerepo.git' blocked
```

I've tried to:

- Purge git and all dependent configurations
- Drop .git folder from project
- Reassign origin

No results. All commands dependent on the remote branch such as "fetch, pull, push, merge" don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading `-` character caused security issues in previous versions of git. It seems your Ubuntu installation contains the fixed Debian version that blocks your fetch attempt. You should rename the repository on BitBucket, and update your local configuration accordingly.

http://marc.info/?l=git&m=150238802328673&w=2

https://release.debian.org/proposed-updates/stable_diffs/git_2.11.0-3+deb9u1.debdiff

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't rename it, 'cause it'll break all links for my team, autodeploy scripts. Do you think downgrading of git will fix this issue?

Comment: It's broken already. And downgrading to avoid a security fix doesn't sound like a good idea to me.